# why trailing backspace is ignored?

Tags: bash, shell

look at some scripts below:

```
[ggfan@localhost ~]$ echo -e "123\b\b"
123
[ggfan@localhost ~]$ echo -e "123\b\bss"
1ss
```

why trailing backspace have no effects in the first one ?
I am running in tilix with bash:

```
bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.0.11(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
__vte_prompt_command
```

Comment: That depends on the terminal or console program. The `\b` is nondestructive on your terminal. It just moves the cursor backward but does not erase the character which is there, until the character is overwritten by another one.

Comment: backspace is not ignored, backspace only _moves cursor position_.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin same results with gnome terminal

Comment: @KamilCuk OMG, I always thought \b works like BACKSPACE on keyboard, now it's  easy to understand.

Comment: It is *nondestructive* on most terminals. It works like the back arrow key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR : `\b` moves the curso one position backwards

---

What happen is that it is evaluated "character by character"

Ie it translate to (first case)

```
Print '1'
Go Next 
Print '2'
Go Next 
Print '3'
Go Next
Go Back
Go Back
```

And second case

```
Print '1'
Go Next 
Print '2'
Go Next 
Print '3'
Go Next
Go Back
Go Back
Print 's' # At that moment we erase what is there so the 2
Go Next 
Print 's' # We erase the 3
Go Next
```

Go next and go back are instruction to move the cursor on the terminal
Ps: This is all pseudocode to understand how it works not actual machine instruction but think at the Turing machine level

And that why
`echo -e "123\b\bs"` print `1s3`